# symfony doctrine method execute just give one object back but why?

Tags: php, oop, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

```
   $result = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Property')->createQuery('p')
                 ->select('min(p.article_id) as article_id')
                 ->where('p.name = ?', 'hotel_number')
                 ->innerJoin('p.Article a')
                 ->andWhere('a.is_active = ?', true)
                 ->groupby('p.string_value')->execute();
```

this should give more then one objects back:

```
$articles = array();
foreach ($result as $temp) {

        $articles[] = $temp['article_id'];
    }
return $articles;
```

I dont understand why this give just one object back if i fire the query in phppgadmin i get 100+ results.
I tried some other querys that worked well in other methods and they give back too just one here:

Anyone have an idea? I never had this situation before and can't fix this issue -.-

Comment: if i remove innerJoin and andWhere methods, i get a list back like i want.

Comment: But i need to join this anyone know why this is like this?
Hope anyone can help me i spend some hours to fix this issue :o and i dont get it :(

Comment: I found out that if i use the (p.article_id) as article_id syntax for alias i get just one back.. if i remove it... like p.article_id i get back an error coz i of need to group fields but if i dont use groupby it works nice , but still not that what i need :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i fixed my issue, its a doctrine bug with alias .. i found this out about google search.

There is a issue with alias names that will given by doctrine

Here is a link to the issue:
[www.doctrine-project.org alias issue](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-585)

For my problem i the fix is easy coz i just want to get all ids that matched the query abouve.

this fixed it: `$result->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_SCALAR)`

HYRATE_SCALAR gives no object arrays back.. look at the doctrine docu here:

[HYDRATE_SCALAR documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html#scalar)

Hope i could help someone with this issue.
Thx 4 help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
->where('p.name = :name')
->andWhere('a.is_active = :active')
->setParameter('name', 'hotel_number')
->setParameter('active', true)
```

Comment: setParameter? i tried but i get errors... never seen this methods on querys